# Regex to match only specific type of URLs?

Tags: regex

I want to create regex for URLs of type:

```
/m/abc/xyz/
```

The above URL should always start with /m/ but abc could be any text followed by a forward slash. Also xyz could be any text followed by a forward slash. The string should end with this forward slash.

For example, `/m/abc/xyz/pqr/` is not a match.

I tried using `\/m\/.+\/.+\/$` but it is even matching `/m/abc/xyz/pqr/`. How do I generate regex for this? Is there any tool where I can put my strings that should match and string that shouldn't and it returns me the regex for it.

Comment: do you want to match only letters from a-z within your slashes or do you want to match everyhing except slashes between them?

Comment: also will the first letter always be an m? and will the folowing allways be as long as three letters? or can there be more or less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `\/m\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/$`

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/BhGBtE/1)

The problem with your current regex is that `.` matches everything, so the second `.+` is probably matching `xyz/pqr`. Using `[^\/]` matches everything except slashes, so it doesn't spill over.

Comment: you can use .+? to match as less as possible

Comment: for examlple \/m\/.+?\/.+?\/

Comment: it is better to group the regex together, since you might have 4 o even more... in that case it will not be efficient to write it the way you did. `^\/m\/(?:[^\/]+\/){2}$` ++1

Comment: The second `.+` matches `pqr` as both `.+` are greedy and the first will give back the minimum required to let the pattern match

Comment: @Phillip `+?` will now work since `$` will force it to end at that particular point ie `.+?\/$` says match to the FIRST `/` such that the next match is `$`. in short match to the end of the string. So `+?\/$` will not work

Answer (score 0):

there you go:

```
\/[a-z]\/[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}\/$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that it is greedy(+) eating everything it can, so make it not greedy to make it work,

try this one

```
\/m\/.+?\/.+?\/
```

[try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/0rIpKD/1)